# Speeding up repetitive task of creating an object and applying a function

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, apply

I'm trying to speed up the following task:

```
# For retrieving Cancer Genome Atlas RNAseq data

library(RTCGA.rnaseq)



# Extract information from sample ID about what kind of samples are in the dataset. 01 means tumor, 06 means metastatic tumor, 10 means healthy etc.

SKCM_sampletype <- as.factor(substr(x = SKCM.rnaseq$bcr_patient_barcode, 14, 15))
summary(SKCM_sampletype)

  01  06 
   1 367 

# Other objects I like to apply this function are (I have 30some objects but showing few below:
# (ACC.rnaseq,BLCA.rnaseq,BRCA.rnaseq,CESC.rnaseq,CHOL.rnaseq,COAD.rnaseq)
```

What I want to do is the having a piece of code that will go through a list of objects and execute the `substring` and `summary` functions. I'd also like to combine all the `summary` stats and plot in a graph that looks like this:

[image: sample image]

My main problems have to do with two main points:
1- How to write a `loop` (or `apply`?) function that will use objects
2- What is the best method of organizing the data to easily use with `ggplot2` package.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: What have you tried? Providing an attempt might help make it clearer what you are after

Comment: I tried putting objects in a list and wrote a loop function with incrementing list index `[[1]], [[2]], ... [[n]]`. That didn't work for using the whole object in the downstream calculations. 

For graphing, I tried converting the `summarize` output into data frame, but I think I was unable to keep the specific cancer identifier (e.g. BRCA, SKCM,...)  with each `sample type` (e.g. 01, 06, 10,..). Hopefully this clears a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `lapply` across the columns of interest, for example:

```
summarise_column <- function(x) {
  cat(x)
  summary(factor(substr(SKCM.rnaseq[[x]], 14, 15)))
}

lapply(c("the", "variables", "I", "would", "like", "to", "summarise"), summarise_column)
```